# checking for matching string

Tags: java, string

I have the following names stored in a text file.

```
|Rafal Dlugosz     |     Ryszard Wojtyna|
|Shuming Wang     |     Junzo Watada|
|Ryszard Wojtyna     |     Rafal Dlugosz|
|Qinghua Hu     |     Daren X. Yu|
|Seok-Beom Roh     |     Tae-Chon Ahn|
|Daren X. Yu    |     Qinghua Hu|
```

Names are separated with `|` symbol. I need to display only those pair of names where the First person name is equal to Second person name in some pair and for the same pair , the Second person name is equal to first name.

Example:

```
|Rafal Dlugosz     |     Ryszard Wojtyna|
|Ryszard Wojtyna     |     Rafal Dlugosz|
|Qinghua Hu     |     Daren X. Yu|
|Daren X. Yu    |     Qinghua Hu|
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated .Thank you.

Comment: you can ask how to separate the strings by `|`...but you should not ask the second part without trying it

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is the following - split the strings on each line and create an Array of pairs in each pair place the first name lexicographical in the first position of the pair and the other name in the second position of the pair. Sort this Array and duplicates will be next to each other.

Also you will have to add somehow the knowledge of the index of each pair in the initial array. Maybe using your own structure is the best option:

```
class Entry implements Comparable {
  String first_name_lexicographically;
  String second_name_lexicographically;
  int initial_index;
  public Entry(String line, int index); // split the line and initilize the fields
}
```

Now create an Array of Entry sort it and duplicate Entries as to your definition will be neighboring.